# Promise with Angular is not assignable to type ts2322

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to do a login in Angular, but I get the error with the promises.
"Type 'Promise<ApiResponse<UserLogged> | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ApiResponse<UserLogged>>'. ts2322

```
     login(user?:string, password?:string):Promise<ApiResponse<User>> {
      return new Promise((resolve) =>  {
        let promise:Promise<ApiResponse<UserLogged>>;
        if (user && password)                           //me estoy logueando
          promise=this.http.post<ApiResponse<UserLogged>>(this.baseUrl + "login", {user: user, password: password}).toPromise();
        else                                            //valido si ya tengo sesion activa en el server
          promise=this.http.get<ApiResponse<UserLogged>>(this.baseUrl + "login").toPromise();
        //proceso respuesta
  
      });
      
    }
```

**apiresponse.ts**

```
export interface ApiResponse<T> extends BaseDTO{
  status: number;
  message?: string;
  data?: T
}
```

**baseDTO**

```
export interface BaseDTO { 
}

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Sorry my English is poor

thank you
```

**User**

```
export interface User extends BaseIdDTO{
  user:string;
  password?:string;
  mail:string;
  name?:string
```

Change in **tsconfig.json** the "strict:true" to "strict: false" and the error disappears.

Comment: I don't see how this error is occuring, can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You can use an online editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to quickly make one!

Answer (score 1):

ok, I thank you for your suggestions, I am a beginner, I will study how to do it with observable

Answer (score 0):

Make clean code to start with ?

```js
login(user?: string, password?: string) {
  if (user && password) return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login', { user, password }).toPromise();
  else return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'login').toPromise();
}
```

Also, you should really use observables, using promises is a downgrade.